# inner border radius does not work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a question about border radius. Basically I am using code to create a sort of spotlight tool to find hidden html. Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pwneth/hj57k/1899/

css:

```
#tail {
border: 1000px solid #fff;
position: absolute;
float: left;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.0);
z-index: 100;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
pointer-events:none;
-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 20px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000000;
box-shadow:         inset 0 0 20px #000000;
}
```

I need to somehow set the border radius of the shape to make it appear as a circle. This is a problem however because this only effects the outside border, which is not something I want to effect. Just the inside of the border.

Comment: Not sure on how to solve your problem, but what you've made is pretty cool!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simpler option:

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hj57k/1912/)</kbd>

Just put the border-radius on the original element.

```
#tail
{
    /* ... */
    border-radius:100%;
}
```

Then just hide everything until the mouse has been over it.

```
body /* or whatever element you want */
{
    display:none;
}
```

Then do this:

```
$(document).bind('mouseenter', function (e) {
    $('body').show();
});
$('body').bind('mouseleave', function (e) {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

This way users will never see the hidden content.

Answer (score 2):

*This solutions is more general and should be used if the desired shape is rounded square or rectangle*

Using a `after` pseudo-element:
http://jsfiddle.net/hj57k/1903/

```
#tail {
    border: 1000px solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.0);
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    pointer-events:none;
}
#tail:after {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 20px #000000;
    box-shadow:         inset 0 0 20px #000000;
    border: 10px solid white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: -10px;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

You need the relative positioning to cover the left-upper edge that would otherwise still be visible. Beware of using box-model or browser inconsistency of calculation dimensions, this is working in webkit, might not be the case for IE.

Answer (score 1):

Without too much change: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hj57k/1906/)

In summary, set `border-radius = border-width + radius`.

Answer (score 0):

Jakub is close, but this produces the intended circle.

http://jsfiddle.net/hj57k/1905/

```
#tail {
    border: 1000px solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.0);
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    pointer-events:none;
}
#tail:after {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 20px #000000;
    box-shadow:         inset 0 0 20px #000000;
    border: 50px solid white;
    border-radius: 999px;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: -50px;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You're right, but in case of circle, Alex's solution is even better :D